# How can I disable and remove XFCE from Debian from SSH?

Tags: debian, ssh, xfce, desktop-environment, headless

I am remotely accessing a server I configured on Debian 11. I want to disable and remove XFCE without losing SSH access (since I don't have physical access to the server right now) and just run it as a headless server. What are the steps?

Answer (score 1):

literally just

```
sudo apt remove xfce4
```

to remove xfce.

Assuming this was the only thing using X.org, the X server will be removed along the way.

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg
```

will explicitly get rid of that as well.

Finally, run

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

to uninstall everything that got useless this way.

Comment: I would recommend before all:
1. Make sure that the SSH server is active in 3rd runlevel.
2. Switch into 3rd system runlevel.

Comment: @stanislav888 "runlevels" do not exist on Debian 11; they're a SysV concept; there exists a very rough emulation of these on modern Linuxes, but these are only for backwards compatibility, you'd generally avoid working with them, because they do not map well to how service lifetime actually is on these. And it's not necessary to do any manual stopping of services: debian's packaging takes care of all this.

Comment: Anyway I would stop services before removing it. There are possible errors by such removing. And XFce4 related services separated shutdown should let to the user some additional information about possible errors. For instance which step breaks ssh connection service shutdown or program removing.  Also, I suppose there is NetworkManager might run into troubles and break some network settings. We don't know the whole user's picture.

Comment: You can manually stop the services, but you can be very sure that debian will stop services that got installed by debian. That's really a pretty well-solved problem. And systemd handles the cross-dependencies between services. You won't do any better!

Comment: I agree with you. apt stops all necessary services. But my idea is to split removing on two steps to have better control of the process and to have one restoring point.